# Insert user IP Address into MySql table using Prepared Statement in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, ip-address

I need to insert user IP Address into MySql table using PreparedStatement. How can I do it?

I tried with following code in Servlet.

```
InetAddress ipaddress;
try {
    ipaddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to know is there any better method than above to get IP Address ?? or I can continue with above code?

```
String insertquery = "insert into tablename (IPAdd) values (?)";

preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(insertquery);
preparedStatement.setString(1, ipaddress);// It's not a string so How can I set values here ?// Getting error here
```

Comment: I didn't do Java for a long while i believe it was `ipaddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress()`

Comment: Should I change my code to above code or mine is fine?

Comment: see @YCF_L answer, his answer is correct `getHostAddress()` return indeed the `127.0.0.1` format and not  `getAddress()` ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the IP then Instead of use :

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, ipaddress);
```

use :

```
// this will return the IP Host Adresse for example 192.168.1.2
preparedStatement.setString(1, ipaddress.getHostAddress());
```

Comment: To add you can also use `try {
        String ipaddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    } `  as the methods should be chainable and use `preparedStatement.setString(1, ipaddress);`..  I didn't do Java for a while but iam pretty sure i did the method chaining like this in the past.. @Tom

Comment: @RaymondNijland don't miss `String ipaddress;`

Comment: Yes thanks, Good point i still could update mine comment.. But iam pretty sure the topicstarter would have figured that one out as the compiler error should be clear enough when using invalid types..

Comment: @YCF_L thanks a lot for helping me out.. Raymond ya good point u made